# Check if CKEditor is initialised

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have mail application with CKEditor,
below code is used to open modal for mail and then create CKEditor on textarea,

```
<textarea id="editor" name="editor" class="border-0"></textarea>
```

```
        $(document).on('click', '.sendEmailButton', function () { 
            //Show mail modal
            $('#compose').modal("show");

            //Init. Editor
            ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .then( newEditor => {
                editor = newEditor;
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
        });
```

My problem is when user click on `.sendEmailButton` it recreates editor again on `textarea`,

How can I check that `textarea` have CKEditor assigned so that on next click it should not recreate it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check as follows and then create the **CKEDITOR** assign the editor to the empty global variable and then check it's empty or not. Initialize it will empty and it will create.on next it will occupaid with editor and not creates it again.

```
var editorVar = "";

$(document).on('click', '.sendEmailButton', function () { 
         //Show mail modal
         $('#compose').modal("show");

         //Init. Editor

            
         if(editorVar == "") {
            ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .then( newEditor => {
                editor = newEditor;
                editorVar = newEditor;
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
         }
});
```